# (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)') display book list

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables, Author and Book, Each book is written by a single author, by cons, the author can write multiple books
In my code, I want to get the book list created by a single author.

```
Book1 =Book.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()
Book1_id= Book1.id
author = Author.objects.filter(pk=Book1_id).values
reponse[author]=author
```

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='user')
        name = models.CharField(default=0)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % self.user

class author(models.Model):
        name_auth = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        Book = models.ForeignKey(compte)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.name_auth)
```

template

```
 {% for t in author %}
                            <td>{{ t.name }}</td>

        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put foreign key to `Book` model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name_auth = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name_auth

class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    name = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

In your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def author_books(request):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'author_books.html', {'author': book.author})
```

Template:

```
{% for book in author.book_set.all %}
    <div>{{ book.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: May be `user` field should be in `Author` model?  If yes then:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    name_auth = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name_auth

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    name = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def author_books(request):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'author_books.html', {'author': author})
```

Template will be the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, inhapilly it has shown nothing, I get the author with this method : author1 =Author.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()                    and I wish to get the book are written by this author ( author1)

Answer (score 0):

If I change the condition, Each book is written by a mutliple author, by against an author can create a (one) book, I want to get the book list created by a single author. In my template, I would view the authors who have written one book